# How do I get commits from origin into my local branch?

Tags: git, github

I have a fork ("origin") of a project on github ("upstream"). I have a branch (`mybranch`), which I pushed to origin and created a pull request from.

Now, someone pushed to my branch on my fork. This means, `mybranch` on origin is ahead of my local `mybranch` by *x* commits.

*How do I get those commits into my local branch, as single commits.*

I've seen solutions of deleting my local branch and using `git reset --hard origin/master`, but that just doesn't feel right. Is there a more natural solution?

Comment: I wonder if the person who did this could make 'mybranch' go back to the previous commit (leaving the branch in a matching state with your local), then do the right thing and create a separate branch to keep her/his work.

Comment: I think, _"as if I had commited them myself?"_ is a problematic requirement. Even if you fetched `mybranch` and vanilla rebased your local branch (i.e. `git rebase origin/mybranch`) on top of it, I suspect this will just do a fast-forward merge, meaning those new extra commits won't have you as the committer. You could however try an interactive rebase (i.e. `git rebase -i origin/mybranch`) and then flag the new commits so you can intervene somehow (e.g. `reword`) so the resulting commits will have you as the committer. However, the latter requires you to force push back up...

Comment: @miqh I wouldn't have a problem with those commits being by a different name. I just want to be able to check them out locally. But `git rebase origin/mybranch` will somehow try to get a lot of commits which aren't mine.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I see. Well, to recap, if you started on your local `mybranch`, did the rebase against `origin/mybranch`, the resulting local `mybranch` will have the "x commits" you're after. Perhaps you've missed some detail in what happened? You can also get a summary list all the commits that aren't in your local `mybranch` but present in `origin/mybranch` with `git log --oneline mybranch..origin/mybranch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> someone pushed to my branch on my fork. This means, mybranch on origin is ahead of my local mybranch by x commits.

Then a simple `git pull --rebase` is enough: it will update your local branch with the remote ones, and replay any local commits (done on your local branch but not yet pushed) on top of those new commits.